# Fabric sdk go app can't connect to orderer on SaveChannel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm trying to deploy my app in fabric sdk go for my hyperledger fabric network, but i have the following error when using the SaveChannel function: "Unable to initialize the Fabric SDK: failed to save channel: create channel failed: SendEnvelope failed: calling orderer 'localhost:7050' failed: Orderer Client Status Code: (2) CONNECTION_FAILED. Description: dialing connection timed out [localhost:7050]"

When i check the orderer container with docker logs i have the following information: "grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "ipnumber:port": remote error: tls: bad certificate" (i didn't put the original ip and port on the post). I have tried with TLS disable in containers, but it didn't work, sending the error "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client"

sdk's config.yaml (only the information about orderer):

```
orderers:
  orderer.app.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.app.com
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/pfc/healthapp/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.app.com/tlsca/tlsca.orderer.app.com-cert.pem

...

entityMatchers:

  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w*)orderer.app.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: grpc://localhost:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.app.com
      mappedHost: orderer.app.com
```

I've tried some tips from other posts like changing the url to localhost:7050, grpcs://localhost:7050, but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" that i've found to make everything works was disable TLS on docker containers and set allow-insecure to true on config.yaml.
Maybe the problem was related to certificates and i didn't have time to work on this issue